# Why does after the import a variable became a constant?

Tags: javascript

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

users.js

```
let users = ["Jack", "Mary"];

export default users;
```

index.js

```
import users from './users.js';

users = [];
```

After executing index.js I get an error:

```
users = [];
      ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

Why? The `users` was clearly defined as a variable not a constant.

Comment: Why would you want reassign it? This seems very much an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) *'The static import statement is used to import **read-only** live bindings which are exported by another module.'*

Comment: It's just a simplified example for better understanding. And I'm also curious what is going on here. Can you let me be curious?

Comment: See the link to the documentation, imported bindings are read-only regardless of how they are declared in the module. That being said `let` within the module may be important for module-scoped reassignment. But reassignment of the imported binding would disconnect the variable from the module, thus losing its utility. If you need a copy you can clone the imported array `let userCopy = [...user];`

Comment: Great, thanks! It turns out that I should re-assign the value of this array inside the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import users from './users.js';
```

is similar to

```
const users = ...
```

in that you cannot assign the value afterward. It's not quite the same because the values can change, but they can only be changed from inside the module. so inside users.js

```
let users = [];

export const setUser(newUsers) {
  users = newUsers
}

export {users, setUser);
```

index.js

```
import {users, setUser} from './users.js'

console.log(users);
console.log(setUser(["a", "b", "c"]));
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't test this though. just one quick example.

Comment: You can *mutate* users after import, you just can't reassign. So a better example would be `setUser(newUser){ users = newUser };` to actually reassign.

Comment: Important to keep in mind that _the module can reassign them though_ (that's what "live binding" means), so it's not quite like `const`. (`export let test = 0; export function inc () { test++ }`, `import { test, inc } from './stuff.js'; console.log(test); inc(); console.log(test)` _will_ print `0` `1`!) - However this does _not_ work with default exports, only named ones.

Answer (score 0):

As @pilchard explained, to accomplish my task I need to change this array inside the module. That's because values that I import are read-only outside the module. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#:%7E:text=The%20static%20import%20statement%20is%20used%20to%20import%20read%2Donly%20live%20bindings%20which%20are%20exported%20by%20another%20module.).

users.js

```js
let users = ["Jack", "Mary"];

function emptyUsers() {
    users = [];
}

export { users, emptyUsers };
```

index.js

```js
import { users, emptyUsers } from "./users.js"
console.log(users); // ["Jack", "Mary"]

emptyUsers(); // instead of users = [];
console.log(users); // []

users.push('Ricky'); // Also I can still change the values of the imported array
console.log(users); // ['Ricky']
```